# Web application will not resolve when using machine name in url

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I am running Windows Server 2008 with IIS7.  On that server I have a third party RIA (Silverlight 3.0) application.  When I am on the machine I can access the application via http://localhost/MyAppRIA and everything works as it should.  When I try to access it via http://{Machine Name}/MyAppRIA I get a blank page with a Silverlight download graphic in the top left corner.

Why can I not access the application by using the machine name.  Do I have a misconfiguration with my DNS or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

That's from the bindings in IIS.  If you ping localhost (it will be 127.0.0.1) and {Machine Name}, they will be different IPs.  Make sure to add a binding for the machine name IP (and optionally host header) for the site that you want it to bind to.

Here's a [video](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/01/29/understanding-iis-bindings.aspx) I put together of IIS bindings that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML using your browser's "view source" command. I bet the app has somehow hard-coded "localhost" into the paths, so when you look at it from another machine it's not able to download the assets it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. If it works from client machines, that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you access by IP address?
You can try using the equivalent of localhost by using:
http://127.0.0.1/MyAppRia

If that works then you could put the machine name into your localhosts file.

On Windows that is usually something like
\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the bindings are correct (Scott Forsyth answer offers some good information), it is possible you could be running into the infamous loopback check.  Have a look at the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Specifically, look at 'Method 2: Disable the loopback check (less-recommended method)'.  Many times this simple registry setting can cause some big headaches.